# Getting IG stories using grapAPI

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, youtube-dl, instagram-story

I'm trying to get IG stories from any user so I can embed with my app (IG downloader) but I can't since it requires access token for every user I want to obtain the sam data.

Here is the API response:

```json
 {
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "A9f9Q_CklsmRXd-1suSk1_w"
   }
}
```

Is there a library like YouTube dlp that can handle the same?